# Nearest int query inside a json field object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-jsonfield

I have a gigantic db with a json field object storing around 30 sub-objects per entry.

Looks like that:

```
{
    "field1": {"someOther": "stuffInside", [...]},
    "field2": {"someOther": "stuffInside", [...]},
    [...]
}
```

All these fields contain one field with a bigint. My objective is to be able to match the closest entry from a given int, for that purpose I made a function that does exactly that:

```
def get_closest_match(
        field: str,
        match: int,
        model: django.db.models.Model,
        return_all_match: bool = False,
        sub_filter: dict or None = None,
):

    log.debug(f"Finding nearest in {model.__name__} with {field} {match}")

    result = model.objects.annotate(abs_diff=Func(F(field) - match, function='ABS'))

    if sub_filter:
        result = result.filter(**sub_filter)

    result = result.order_by('abs_diff')

    if not return_all_match:
        return result.first()

    return result
```

While this function works great for int fields, I wasn't able to make it compatible with jsonfields, is there a way to make my function work with an int inside a jsonfield ?

My first idea was to make a separate table storing only those bigints so I could use my method, which in fact works, but as mentionned above, each entry has around 30 objects and I have millions of entries so performance wise it is not very optimal (It also make data duplication which is not good)

Comment: Please *don't* use json blobs if the structure of the data is known. JSON blobs are useful if the structure of the data is not known in advance.

Comment: JSON is used because the data is dynamic and not known

Comment: Is the data dynamic or is the structure dynamic? `All these fields contain one field with a bigint.`, in this case the structure is known and the data is dynamic. For performance it would make sense to store this bigint in its own table, probably with other known items. You could even remove this content from your json, if you don't want to duplicate data. (don't forget, storage is cheap)

Comment: Already tough about it as mentioned above `My first idea was to make a separate table storing only those bigints` but this method has performance issues because it require so many queries that it's not worth it, but basically yea the data is dynamic, but the structure is not "known" as well, it has eg 36 possibilities and not all of them can there

Comment: just or reference a realistic scale of what would be stored in the other table would be 1 for 30, on my test db i only have ~2800 entries and it generate more than 84000 bigints in the other table which is already super slow, so imagine on millions of entries (cause yes there will be millions of entries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually super dumb, before trying the second table fix I tried to use my method above with a cast on the json field, which in fact worked but didn't return the closest match because the ordering was false.

After some big debuging here is the correct version of the said method with json field support:

```
def get_closest_match(
        field: str,
        match: int,
        model: django.db.models.Model,
        return_all_match: bool = False,
        sub_filter: dict or None = None,
):

    log.debug(f"Finding nearest in {model.__name__} with {field} {match}")

    result = model.objects.annotate(abs_diff=Func(Cast(F(field), models.BigIntegerField()) - match, function='ABS'))

    if sub_filter:
        result = result.filter(**sub_filter)

    result = result.order_by('abs_diff')

    if not return_all_match:
        return result.first()

    return result
```

The issue was just that my `Cast` was casting an Int instead of a BigInt... So yep completely works with JSONField if you use the correct syntaxing aka `jsonobject__key_1__key_2` more info on [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)

PS: The method above is fully modular and can be used to perform the queries I need with JSON Fields, however I haven't tested other uses cases with regular ints, it shouldn't have any issues but in case you could always add a new arg that contains the desired field for the cast (or just make a condition to not cast if field is an int or smth), I don't see a scenario where this would be an issue but you never know